# Android Notification. Экран блокировки

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Как запросить  разрешение на показ уведомления на закрытом экране.

На моем Redmi 7A (Android 10) у каждого приложения есть данный пункт - Разрешить уведомления на экране блокировки.

Как я могу получить из кода данное разрешение? Пока что оно у меня не активно.

Для примера, такие приложения как Telegram, WhatsApp сразу после установки имеют данное разрешение, хочу реализовать что-то подобное в своем проекте.